# C#/Xamarin List Emptying Itself

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.android

I'm working in C#/Xamarin on the Android portion of a cross-platform PCL solution - I'm very new to Xamarin and mobile dev in general.

In a loop, I'm trying to query a REST service for some geoinformation (which works fine), deserialise the result into an object (also works fine) and then add said object to a list (works fine *once*). The problem I have is that every time the method getting the deserialised object returns, the collection for them has magically been emptied (Count is 0).

This is where the list lives:

```
List<Thingy> thingyList = new List<Thingy>();

//Setting some variables
//.
//.

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    //Positive offset loop
    for (double latUnderTest = Lat; latUnderTest <= latOffsetCoordsMax; latUnderTest += latOffset3M)
    {
        //Bound to our max coords
        latUnderTest = latUnderTest > latOffsetCoordsMax ? latOffsetCoordsMax : latUnderTest;

        for (double longUnderTest = Long; longUnderTest <= longOffsetCoordsMax; longUnderTest += longOffset3M)
        {
            //Bound to our max coords
            longUnderTest = longUnderTest > longOffsetCoordsMax ? longOffsetCoordsMax : longUnderTest;

            //Don't query areas we've already done
            if (HasLocationBeenQueried(latUnderTest, longUnderTest))
            {
                continue;
            }

            Thingy thingy = await GetThingyForCoords(latUnderTest, longUnderTest, client);

            if (thingy != null)
            {
                thingyList.Add(thingy);
                AdjustQueriedArea(latUnderTest, longUnderTest);
            }
        }
    }

    //Negative offset loop, not reached for the purpose of this
    //.
    //.

    return thingyList;
}
```

Yes, the loops are a bit disgusting but this was just meant to be a quick and dirty first run. Anyway, this is the method making the request:

```
public async Task<Thingy> GetThingyForCoords(double Lat, double Long, HttpClient Client)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await Client.GetAsync(aUrlIKnowWorks))
        {
            return resp.IsSuccessStatusCode ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thingy>(await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()) : null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm not adding the same object every loop iteration or anything silly like that and the request isn't returning nulls every time so I'm at a loss - my guess is this is some weird threading-related issue stemming from using async on mobile, or some undocumented incompatibility between HttpClient and Xamarin, but I don't really know where to go from here debugging-wise.

Comment: You only reference thingyList once, `thingyList.Add(thingy);` which will not empty it.  So either: 1. You are never actually calling `Add`, which you check with debugging/logging.  Or 2.  You are referencing thingyList in a second place you haven't shown us.  Maybe post this in the question?  Or 3. You are calling this entire function multiple times, so when you look in the debugger and see an empty list you are actually looking at a different `new List()`, which would explain why it was empty.  You could check that again with some logging to see how often `new List()` is called.

Comment: @BuhBuh Thanks for responding - to your points: 1) `Add` is definitely being called, I verify the count has increased in the debugger afterwards. 2) The only other reference is when it's returned, which I've now added. 3) This method should only be called once, but even if not the debugger should hold it in place, no?

Comment: `the debugger should hold it in place` ?? Don't know what you mean by that.  No?  I think you should add a breakpoint on the `new List()` to actually test how many times it is called, rather than assuming. 
If all of your answers are correct then there can't be any way it is empty.

Comment: Arghhh, got it - the method was accidentally tied to location updates, and I guess because the method is async, while the debugger had stopped for me to look at the count, the method was being re-called so I was essentially looking at a different instance of `Count` every time... Will post an answer to same effect. I loathe problems that only exist _because_ I'm debugging to look for problems. /facepalm

Comment: Ah, sorry... hang on, I'll delete mine and give you it, your 3rd point is what made me realise my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for that. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you only ever call `list.Add()` there is no way the list can be emptying itself.  Therefore you must be looking a different list.

The function must be being called more than once, creating a new list each time.  When debugging it is not always obvious that you are at a different list on a different thread.

---

As an afterthought: Something which might help you detect this kind of issue in the future is to turn on "Show threads in source".

[image: Show threads in source]

Then, when debugging you will see these icons on the left, hinting that there is a second thread currently waiting at that line of code.
Although, personally I find them a bit unclear.

[image: Thread icon]